# Looking for measurement for nonlinear model

Tags: nonlinear-regression, k-nearest-neighbour

I use KNN regression to train out a model. The model estimates running time of a program based on different inputs, and the output is a single variable, which is time (double type).

I want to evaluate this model. I have a list of observation times and a list of prediction times. I would like to know how I can evaluate the model based on these two lists. What kind of measurements can I use?

Two lists for example:

Observation List: {0.01, 0.03, 0.02, 0, 0.02}

Prediction List: {0.05, 0.02, 0.04, 0.37, 0.05}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use MSE/RMSE or even AIC/BIC.

Comment: I would like to know What kind of value of MSE/RMSE can be viewed as good prediction?